# Count fields in a MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "field1": "some string",
    "field2": "another string",
    "field3": 123
}
```

I'd like to be able to iterate over the entire collection, and find the entire number of fields there are. In this example document there are 3 (I don't want to include _id), but it ranges from 2 to 50 fields in a document. Ultimately, I'm just looking for the average number of fields per document.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
PRIMARY> var count = 0;
PRIMARY> db.my_table.find().forEach( function(d) { for(f in d) { count++; } });
PRIMARY> count
1074942
```

This is the most simple way I could figure out how to do this. On really large datasets, it probably makes sense to go the Map-Reduce path. But, while your set is small enough, this'll do.

This is `O(n^2)`, but I'm not sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 12):

> Iterate over the entire collection, and find the entire number of fields there are

Now you can utilise [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) operator [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) ([SERVER-23310](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23310)) to turn keys into values and count them. This operator is available in MongoDB v3.4.4+

For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
         {"$project":{"numFields":{"$size":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}}}, 
         {"$group":{"_id":null, "fields":{"$sum":"$numFields"}, "docs":{"$sum":1}}}, 
         {"$project":{"total":{"$subtract":["$fields", "$docs"]}, _id:0}}
])
```

First stage `$project` is to turn all keys into array to count fields. Second stage `$group` is to sum the number of keys/fields in the collection, also the number of documents processed. Third stage `$project` is subtracting the total number of fields with the total number of documents (As you don't want to count for `_id` ).

You can easily add [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) to count for average on the last stage.

Comment: Sorry to ask a noob question, but what environment are you running this command in?

Comment: @samjewell In the MongoDB shell (native to MongoDB) or in a shell of a client such as Robo 3T

Answer (score 3):

You could create a Map-Reduce job.  In the Map step [iterate over the properties of each document as a javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), output the count and reduce to get the total.

Comment: This tipped me over the edge. I was hesitant to actually write that... but I did, and it was actually pretty simple (I skipped the Map-Reduce part though)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple way just find() all value and for each set of record get size of array.

```html
db.getCollection().find(<condition>)
```

then for each set of result, get the size of array.

```html
sizeOf(Array[i])
```