# MongoDB - Aggregate fields inside and object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following dataset in MongoDB:

```
{
  _id: 574718ec2bc91f565db33897,
  topic: {
    T69: 0.9566255761668587
  }
},
{
  _id: 574718ec2bc91f565db33899,
  topic: {
    T257: 0.046038051058499445,
    T2: 1.8206715756325407,
    T31: 0.08838710118945285
  }
},
{
  _id: 574718ec2bc91f565db33889,
  topic: {
    T95: 0.37718859499517865,
    T40: 0.2620479937270479,
    T2: 0.3594989449758472,
    T1: 1.9161288780994465
  }
}
```

I've been trying to create an aggregation query which returns the sum of all topics, Tn, over the set of all such documents. Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction? Since I'm new to MongoDB I couldn't find an answer to this problem (though this seemed related [$unwind an object in aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189243/unwind-an-object-in-aggregation-framework)).

Comment: topic is an array or subdocument?

Comment: @profesor79 topic is a subdocument and T1, T2, ..., Tn are fields in this subdocument.

Comment: Unwind works with arrays that was reason for my question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count fields in a MongoDB Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811379/count-fields-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it with the mongoDB aggregation framework (that works better with collections/array of subdocs), but is pretty simple with a map/reduce. For example you can try with:

```
db.YOURCOLLECTION.mapReduce(
  function () {
    var topic = this.topic;
    Object.keys(topic).forEach(function(k) {
      emit(k, topic[k]);
    });
  },
  function (key, values) {
     return Array.sum(values);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Our best bet here is [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/). In our `map` function all we need is to iterate over the "topic" property and emit the value. To get the total sum in the collection we need to "emit" with `null` as key value.

In the reduce function we simply use the `Array.sum` method to return the sum.

```
db.coll.mapReduce(function() { 
    for (var key in this.topic) { 
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.topic, key)) {
            emit(null, this.topic[key]) 
        }
    }}, 
    function(key, value) { 
        return Array.sum(value);
    }, 
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

which produces:

```
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "value" : 5.826586715844872
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 26,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 3,
        "emit" : 8,
        "reduce" : 1,
        "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If you want the "sum" for each document, simply call `emit(this._id, this.topic[key])` in your map function instead of `emit(null, this.topic[key])`