# Count number of fields have data in a collection with aggregate mongodb

Tags: mongodb, count, field, aggregate

This is my collections with sample database:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9797b480591678e0771190"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(172), 
    "temp_name" : "Regular Employment", 
    "individual_setting" : false, 
    "employment_category" : "Regular Employee", 
    "branch_office" : "Cebu Branch Office", 
    "availability_status" : "Incumbent", 
    "req_working_hours" : "08:00", 
    "fixed_brk_time_from" : "12:00", 
    "fixed_brk_time_to" : "13:00", 
    "sch_time_setting" : [
        {
            "holiday" : [
                "Saturday", 
                "Friday"
            ], 
            "biweekly_odd" : [

            ], 
            "biweekly_even" : [
                "Saturday"
            ], 
            "clock_in_mon" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_tue" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_wed" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_thu" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_fri" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_sat" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_sun" : null, 
            "clock_in_hol" : null, 
            "clock_out_mon" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_tue" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_wed" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_thu" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_fri" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_sat" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_sun" : null, 
            "clock_out_hol" : null, 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a9797b480591678e077118f")
        }
    ], 
    "date_to_start" : ISODate("2018-03-01T06:03:32.050+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-03-01T06:03:32.066+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-03-01T06:03:32.066+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Between the field `clock_in_mon` to `clock_in_hol` under `sch_time_setting` field, I want to count how many fields that have data or is not null. Because each staff has different time_setting, so those fields might have few data in other staff.

The expected count for this is: 6, because only `clock_in_mon` to `clock_in_sat` have data.

I tried code from here [Count fields in a MongoDB Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811379/count-fields-in-a-mongodb-collection) but I can't make it in my case.

Comment: show your current attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following aggregation:

```
    db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            totalClockIns: {
              $map: {
                   input: "$sch_time_setting",
                   as: "setting",
                   in: {
                      _id: "$$setting._id",
                      kvPairs: {
                        $objectToArray: "$$setting"
                      }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            totalClockIns: {
                $map: {
                   input: "$totalClockIns",
                   as: "clockIn",
                   in: {
                      _id: "$$clockIn._id",
                      count: { 
                        $size: { $filter: { input: "$$clockIn.kvPairs", as: "pair", cond: { $and: [
                        {$eq: [{ $indexOfBytes: [ "$$pair.k", "clock_in_" ] },0]},{$ne: ["$$pair.v",null]}] } } } }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

To analyze your document you need to compare key names. To do that you have to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) operator which transforms and object to a list of key-value pairs. Then you can find those pairs where `key` name starts with `clock_` (using [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/index.html)) and where value is not equal `null`. Using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) you can get rid of all the other pairs and the all you need to do is to use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get the length of an array.

This will give you following result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a9797b480591678e0771190"), "totalClockIns" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5a9797b480591678e077118f"), "count" : 12 } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks mickl but i just want to count fields only from 'clock_in_mon' to 'clock_in_hol'. Not included the clockout. So expected count must be 6.

Comment: @noyruto88, modified my answer

Comment: Thank you @mickl. I understand now.