# MongoDB sorting by documents with more fields filled out

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently trying to get a query that I can find by zip code (very easy)

```
e.g. db.col.find({zip: 60010})
```

but then sort based on how many fields on the Mongo document are filled out (or not null; not so easy)

How can I do this in a fast an efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `objectToArday` and `addFields` then `size`

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811379/count-fields-in-a-mongodb-collection)

But it's costlier option than having one field which tells the count of fields in that document.

You can decide based on read or write intensive application.